# How to add a manual cell in each table row after an ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-table, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm building a table that is populated by ng-repeat going through a list that comes from the database. This part works fine, but I want to have a checkbox that lets the user select which rows are deleted. I'd also like to have a checkbox on the table header that works as a select all button.

The problem is that, as I understand it, the ng-repeat loop includes everything inside the row in question leaving me unable to insert a manual cell between the loop and the end of the row.

Is there a way to add an additional cell between the loop and the end of the row, for example by using ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat end?

Here is an example of my attempts. This one did not work, obviously.

```
<table>
    <tr><th ng-repeat=" e in poistoavaimet">{{e}}</th></tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="i in poistolista | filter:sukunimiVal | filter:etunimiVal">
        <td ng-repeat-start=" key in poistoavaimet">{{i[key]}}</td>
        <td ng-repeat-end>
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="poistovalinta.{{$index}}"> 
          {{$index}}</input>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

poistoavaimet contains the extracted keys from the array. Poistolista is the array itself from which the keys are extracted and it contains the data from the database. Poistovalinta is a variable for the values of the checkboxes. `poistovalinta.{{$index}}` was an attempt to create an entry in poistovalinta -array that has the key of the index of the row.

I'll add a snippet of the code responssible for handling these variables from the controller:

```
    $scope.haePoistettavat = function(){
            $http.get('/opiskelijahaku', {params: {'optio':2}})
              .then(function(res){
                    $scope.poistolista = res.data.message;
                    $scope.poistoavaimet = Object.keys($scope.poistolista[0]);
                    $scope.adminLista = {};
                    $scope.adminLista['poisto'] = true;
            }, function(error){
                    console.log(error)
            });
    }
```

This function sends a http get to the server with an option that tells the server to return the correct list. The response is stored in `$scope.poistolista` and the keys are extracted in to the array `$scope.poistoavaimet`. `$scope.adminLista` contains true/false values which link to ng-show in multiple objects. The idea is to only show one of them at the time. This is not directly linked to the question.

Comment: `ng-repeat` is simply iterating on a data set provided. For your purpose you just have to modify that data set and `ng-repeat` will do it for you. if you want to add a row in between, you can modify your dataset to have index in-between desired bounds inserted. Assuming its an array you can use `push` which will add at the end of the array or you can use splice to insert in between and combine and return a new array

Comment: What's in `poistoavaimet` and `poistolista`? The different language makes it more confusing

Comment: What is `poistoavaimet`, `poistolista`, and `poistovalinta`? It's hard to read the code because the words all look the same to me. It looks like the `<th>` cells don't match the `<td>` cells. The closing tag `</input>` is illegal HTML. `ng-model=poistovalinta.{{$index}}` doesn't make sense.

Comment: You do not need `ng-repeat-start/end`, just add your elements before/after your `ng-repeat`...

Comment: poistoavaimet contains the extracted keys from the array. Poistolista is the array itself from which the keys are extracted and it contains the data from the database. Poistovalinta is a variable for the values of the checkboxes. poistovalinta.{{$index}} was an attempt to create an entry in poistovalinta -array with the key of the index of the row.

Comment: @RaphaMex Thanks alot! I was under some serious misconception about ng-repeat that I didn't even think it would work like that.

Comment: @nyoatype: Welcome :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @RaphaMex for clearing up my misunderstanding about how ng-repeat works!

The solution is exactly what he said. Just add the cell after the repeat and it works.

Here is the fixed version:

```
            <table>
                    <tr><th ng-repeat=" e in poistoavaimet">{{e}}</th><th><input id="kaikki" type="checkbox" ng-model="kaikkiVal"></th></tr>
                    <tr ng-repeat="i in poistolista | filter:sukunimiVal | filter:etunimiVal">
                            <td ng-repeat=" key in poistoavaimet">{{i[key]}}</td>
                            <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="poistovalinta"></td>
                    </tr>
            </table>
```